# Server Error '/demo' in Application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

The error is shown as below:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 69: public Boolean UserAuthentication(string UserID, string
>   Password)
>
> Line 70: {
>
> Line 71: Con.Open(); // Red Color - showing this is the error.
>
> Line 72:
>
> Line 73:         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM
>   LoginList WHERE UserID = '" + UserID + "' AND Password = '" + Password
>   + "'", Con);

My Connection string was written as below:

```
static SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(
     @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
     AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;
     Integrated Security=True;
     User Instance=True");
```

Note: Firewall service is disable and SQL server name no error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
static SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(
 @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
 Initial Catalog=Database.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True;
 User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Nope. Still same outcomes.